# Moveit gdb debugging

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run move_group code through gdb. I compiled moveit from sources with --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug.
Still, it seems like debug information haven't been lost.
What I did:
I ran my own node that uses move_group.plan(my_plan) and tried to step through plan(). But it doesn't step into the function like it hadn't written debugging data.
I use ros kinetic
Would use any help. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294262/moveit-gdb-debugging/) by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on 2018-07-07**:
Are you sure you're using ROS2? Is there MoveIt available for ROS2 already? It's just to make sure. I am working with ROS1 and I'm not sure if there is a bit difference when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess in your case `move_group` is actually a `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface`.
This class is only a ROS-wrapper which sends a goal to a ROS action.

If you want to debug the planning process you have to run the `move_group` node in gdb and set a breakpoint on the function that receives the action goal.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately I don't have a solution, but I'm dealing with the same issue. It is really confusing and there seems to be no documentation concerning this. Did you manage to resolve this?

Perhaps if we brainstorm what we tried, we will be able to move forward.

1. Did you enable debugging in your launch file?
   If you're launching a whole move group, you can find this option in the move_group.launch on the top.
2. This above step requires a gdb_settings.gdb file.
   This is referring to this [type of input](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files) apparently.
3. In my case I have (not sure how) managed to activate a process `gdb -x gdb_settings.gdb ... move_group...` to which I can attach using `gdb attach <process id>`.  However trying to explore with `info functions` doesn't show any functions relevant to ROS or MoveIt! or anything such.

---

Originally posted by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) with karma: 65 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1